# Concerns about existing database table

Tags: database-design

Apparently 3 or 4 live web sites use this table and the owner doesn't want to spend the time to fix it and the code that accesses it. What do you typically do in this situation, it doesn't seem like I have any choice other than to deal with it.

[image: O_o]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Oded, It's huge and contains things unrelated to members such as CC, address. They use int data type instead of bit for true/false.

Comment: I understand that the table is a mess (denormalized, bad data types etc...), but what problem are you, in fact, trying to solve here?

Comment: @nick, you can't fix all the bad code in the world! The owner doesn't want to fix it, so hold your nose to keep from passing out from the smell of that table, and plop on top and move on.  Your paycheck will still cash even if the table is crap.  This is what people mean when they cry about working on "legacy code" (crap someone else made and you are stuck maintaining).  Welcome to software development!

Comment: @KM, imagine 100 more tables (not as big as this one) with no foreign keys or database diagrams. A 10 min task takes quite a while to track down the correct tables to work with. Thanks for the advice, I will do my best.

Comment: I think you could get better traction with this question if you actually made it a question - perhaps, "How to deal with a legacy DB table" and gave some more insight into what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: @Nick, been there done that.  I worked on tables where there were no FKs defined, and the join columns were different names and data types (table scan).  Your best bet is to build a nice diagram as you learn the system.  So, start with the main important tables and diagram how they join.  As you learn the system, add additional tables and how they join, etc. etc.  With such a diagram, your job becomes easier.  Actually a hundred tables isn't that many, that is more like a large project.

Comment: @KM: They're pretty open to all kinds of freaks of nature :)

Comment: @KM, can you imagine the html and css structure?... inline css, using divs with specified heights as padding O_o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client insists on you using this structure (and as it appears that he has *several* websites running with it, the client probably does), you need to adapt yourself to it. It is a horrible mess, but unless you get paid to fix it, you can't really tell the boss what to do.

There are several dependent applications and unless you can change them, you need to keep using it.

There are ways to mitigate this issue - if you have the time, create a better structure, migrate the data and create a *view* over the new structure that is identical to the above and that can be used seamlessly by applications that insist on using the old/broken structure.

The only solution is incremental cleanups, and this assumes you can also cleanup the application code that uses this table.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the database contains a hundred tables, none of them use foreign keys and there is no database diagrams set up. I will do my best to work with it though.

Comment: @nick - The approach I outlined (incremental migration), is really the only way to clean such a mess up. And again, if this isn't your job, all you can do is raise your concerns and get on with the job (or say sayonara if you don't want to deal with it).

Comment: Paragraph 3 is especially important. This is how to refactor a database when you have existing clients that cannot be changed. The owner may not be aware that there is a way to fix this going forward for new clients while still preserving the functionality of the existing clients.

Comment: we too have a legacy DB2 database that is full of crap!  I call it the platypus database because it was designed the same way a platypus was!  Putting bits and pieces from other "animals" together to make one weird one!